# dialog not showing which causes issue as i need to wait for asynTask return before moving on

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog

I have a fragment activity. When i click the fragment it fires a listener which fires an AsyncTask. I need the Async tasks result before moving to the next line of code in the listener i.e i need the asyncTask to be synchronous.

To do this i usually use a dialog to effectively make user wait for asyncTask onPostExecute(). But my dialog isnt appearing and my code is moving on past the asyncTask and into the bundle code which then adds null variables, sad face.

Here is the bones of my fragment class, let me know if you need anything else, i'm conscious of posting too much but i am sure its connected to the structure of my class and fact i'm using fragments.

```
public class Login_StaggeredGrid_Fragment_Activity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private ArrayList<String[]> gameSummaryTilesData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            final StaggeredGridFragment fragment = new StaggeredGridFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    private class StaggeredGridFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener
    {
                private StaggeredGridView mGridView;
                private boolean mHasRequestedMore;
                private TilesAdapter mAdapter;

                @Override
                public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setRetainInstance(true);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sgv, container, false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    //Encapsulate all within a post cereate from a async task or call a blocking http call
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                        View header = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header_footer, null);
                        mGridView.addHeaderView(header);
                    }

                    if (mAdapter == null) {
                        mAdapter = new TilesAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.summary1_value);
                    }

                    for (String[] data : loginTilesData) {
                        mAdapter.add(data); //Add each loginTilesData TileAdapter element to an mAdapter where it will be further broken down and used by the TileAdapter
                    }

                    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
                    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // Loading Games in Background Thread
                        new GetGamesSummaryTiles().execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login_StaggeredGrid_Fragment_Activity.this, GamesSummary_Fragment_Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra("gamesSummaryTilesData", gameSummaryTilesData);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

       /**
     * Background Async Task to get data for next activity by making HTTP Request
     * */
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog qDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String url_login ="http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/XXXX.php";
    class GetGamesSummaryTiles extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            qDialog = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
            qDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            qDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            qDialog.setCancelable(false);
            qDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject jsonLogin = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET", params);

            pk_http pk_dbComms = new pk_http();
            try {
                gameSummaryTilesData = pk_dbComms.formatHttpResponse_SummaryTile(jsonLogin);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                String test = e.getStackTrace().toString();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonLogin.toString();
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)
        {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all questions
            qDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
             /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

              }
             });*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do the  bundle code into the **onPostExecute()** method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the your intent calling code in your onPostExecute method and your problem will be solved

move the below code from onItemClick() to onPostExceute

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login_StaggeredGrid_Fragment_Activity.this, GamesSummary_Fragment_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("gamesSummaryTilesData", gameSummaryTilesData);
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: thx -  that should do it alright. what if i want to move this asynctask into a class of its own and use it for all my fragments? What would i pass into it?

Comment: Make a base class of Async class and call it into any fragment and activity you want to execute.

Comment: If i cant wait for the async class that means i have to do all my work in the onPostExecute which will probably also entail setting activity control attr. How can i do this in a separate AsyncTask class - pass the context?

Comment: When you want the code to be executed in serialization with execution of async class then you have to move your code to onPostExecute method of async class.

Answer (score 0):

put your below code in postExecute() methode of asyncTask...

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Login_StaggeredGrid_Fragment_Activity.this, GamesSummary_Fragment_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("gamesSummaryTilesData", gameSummaryTilesData);
                startActivity(i);
```